# How to send email only when select query returns data

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

This is my first time posting a question. How do I send an email, only when the select query returns data and prevent blank emails being sent when the select query returns no data?

Currently, the results of my select query go to a temp table, then the results are sent via a CSV file attachment, in an email and a SQL job has been created, so it's scheduled to run a at certain time every day, whether the select query returns data or not

Any help to resolve this issue, would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: what is your platform? are you using a programming language? are you using SSIS? are you using SQL Server Job?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to utilize EXISTS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Here is some pseudocode:

```
If EXISTS(select * from SomeTable where SomeCriteria = 1)
    YourLogicToSendEmailHere
```